# Laravel shared session in seperate domain and subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have Laravel app with 2 domain example.com and example.net. In the same app, I need two different sessions, session for example.com and different session for example.net and sub.example.net. If I set SESSION_DOMAIN to '.example.net' session for example.com not working. For all domain, I have separate Controller. Any Idea?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: SESSION_DOMAIN = null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. Need to use middleware for part of app where is used example.net

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CookiesDomain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        config(['session.domain' => '.example.net']);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And in default config for cookies:

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => '.example.com',
```